# How to alert the script name that opened the window

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am using multiple scripts to get to a sub-window. I want to know how to alert the parent window name? Is there anything like `alert(window.opener)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `window.opener` exists as a reference to the window that opened the current window.  It's supported in at least Chrome, Firefox, IE and Opera.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.opener
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534309(VS.85).aspx

If you're looking to get a reference to the function that created the window, you could add it yourself as a property of the window:

```
var win = window.open("test.htm", "myWin");

// set a global var in the window to this function
win.openerFunction = arguments.callee;
```